# Validation Unexpected {

Tags: php, mysql, validation

When im trying to validate my data im getting this error, and i dont understand why it is 'Unexpected'

```
//Requests fields from form on previous page  
 $CDID = $_REQUEST['CDID'];
 $CDTitle = isset($_REQUEST['CDTitle']) ? $_REQUEST['CDTitle'] :null;
 $CDYear = isset($_REQUEST['CDYear']) ? $_REQUEST['CDYear'] :null;
 $catID = isset($_REQUEST['catID']) ? $_REQUEST['catID'] :null;
 $pubID = isset($_REQUEST['pubID']) ? $_REQUEST['pubID'] :null;


if(empty($CDTitle) || (empty($CDYear) || (empty($catID) || (empty($pubID)){
die("<p> You must enter all fields</p>\n");}
```

Comment: Downvoting questions to hell ... you are doing good SO.

Comment: @eisberg So you believe counting somebody's parentheses to find a trivial error should be crowdsourced?

Comment: @lanzz I believe helping him would be fine. Everyone of us started somewhere and sometime.

Comment: @eisberg But people _are_ helping him. Downvoting has nothing to do with helping; it indicates exactly what the tooltip says: lack of research.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement should read:

`if(empty($CDTitle) || empty($CDYear) || empty($catID) || empty($pubID)){`

You had too many brackets, so php expected to see more closing brackets to close your conditions. I've removed the unnecessary brackets.

Comment: ahhhh yes!!! that explains it

Comment: @BenArmstrong If it helped you, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

excess of brackets..

change:

```
if(empty($CDTitle) || (empty($CDYear) || (empty($catID) || (empty($pubID)){
```

to:

```
if(empty($CDTitle) || empty($CDYear) || empty($catID) || empty($pubID)){
```

Comment: This still won't work, you have an extra bracket before the last `empty`

Comment: An excess of brackets would never cause a script to fail, as long as the syntax is correct and they are in pairs.

Comment: @F4r-20 Except they're not really in pairs in the question.

Comment: in this case brackets arent in pair

Comment: No but that isn't what @vlcekmi3 was getting at. His answer was implying that the brackets around each `empty()` was the cause of the problem. And FYI your syntax is *still* not correct.

Answer (score 0):

) missing :

```
if(empty($CDTitle) || (empty($CDYear) || (empty($catID) || (empty($pubID)){
```

should be :

```
if(empty($CDTitle) || (empty($CDYear)) || (empty($catID)) || (empty($pubID))){
```

or

```
if(empty($CDTitle) || empty($CDYear) || empty($catID) || empty($pubID)){
```

Comment: This also won't work, the second and third `emptys` need either the opening bracket removed or an additional closing bracket.